# Обновить сущность в БД. one-to-many

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistance

Есть две сущности-таблицы с соотношением one-to-many.  Использую Spring Data + JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "owners")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Owner.books",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("books"))
public class Owner implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "owner_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "owner_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<>(0);

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Book.owner",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("owner"))
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "book_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Owner owner;

}
```

В классе контроллера из этих сущностей я делаю `ViewModel`, которую отправляю клиенту на html страницу. На клиентской стороне я делаю изменения в `ViewModel` - изменяю имя или добавляю/удаляю Книжки (фактически работаю с ID книжек) у `OwnerViewModel`. Затем изменённый объект `OwnerViewModel` я отправляю назад на сервер, делаю маппинг из `OwnerViewModel` -> `Owner`. И мне нужно сохранить этот `Owner` с учётом добавленных/удалённых Book.

Ну тут проблема - я не знаю как мне сохранить `Owner` - потому что после маппинга со стороны клиента приходит лишь набор ID книг. Как мне сохранить новый обновлённый `Owner` в базу?

```
public class OwnerViewModel {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<BookSimpleInfo> books= new HashSet<>(0);

}
public class BookSimpleInfo {

    private Long id;

}
```

есть идеи у кгого ? нужно помощ

Answer (score 1):

- Достаете `Owner` по `ownerViewModel.id`.
- Обновляете ему name, пробегаете по коллекции books и проверяете, есть ли `book.id` в `ownerViewModel.books`. Если есть, то удаляете `id` из `ownerViewModel.books`, иначе удаляете `book` из `owner.books`.
- Достаем по оставшимся `id` в `ownerViewModel.books` книги, и добавляем их в `owner.books`.
- Cохраняем `owner`, перед этим добавив в Entity к полю `books` каскад `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}`